# To have multiple records for same user in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I wish to have a multiple records for uname (same user) in DynamoDB, but the record gets updated when I do a POST request . I wish to multiple records for the same user instead of one.
i.e : After POST method with all attributes, the records gets updated instead of generating a new record.

On GET request : 'url/uname' gives only one record.

I wish to get multiple records, how can i achieve this ?

```
service: Test1

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

functions:
  create:
    handler: create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: form
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: form
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: form/{uname}
          method: get
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: uname
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: uname
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 10
          WriteCapacityUnits: 10
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [GSI: global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). In a GSI, there is no constraint of one item per partition key. Here's what you can do:

Change your main table so that the primary key has a unique value for each user request. Every time you need to save a user request, you generate a new primary key like this (just an example): `randomInteger[1:10000] + timestamp + userID`. This should be enough to avoid two requests from having the same partition key.

With each of those items, also save the userID as a separate attribute (could be your sort key or a regular attribute). Of course, also save all other attributes you need.

In your GSI, set the userID as the primary key. When you need all items from a given user, just query the GSI (not the main table) for the userID and you'll get all of them.